# Unable to get Azure keyvault secret after deployment

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to get keyvault secret in my application it is working fine in local(while executing application with my AD credential), But after deploying my AppService it is not working. Below are the code and role(IAM) which I assigned in Azure Portal under. (Role: key vault contributor) for both Me and AppService.

```
public async Task<string> GetSecret()
    {
        var keyVaultUrl = "https://mykv.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret";
        AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
        var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        return secret.Value;
    }
public myclass()//ctor
    {
    var sce=GetSecret().Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy your application to azure, go to your app service> `Identity` > `turn on` your System assigned Managed Identity.

Then go to your azure key vault, click `Access policies` and `add access policy`.

Choose `Secret permission` with at least **Get and List** permission. Then in `Select principal` attribute,  click your webapp service principal you registered before.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this tutorial to [Connect to azure key vault from an ASP.NET core app using azure managed identity](https://medium.com/@taithienbo/connect-to-azure-key-vault-from-an-asp-net-core-app-using-azure-managed-identity-e267b79b9df4).